# Store ObjectsIds of Different Types in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I reference multiple `ObjectId`s of different types in a single reference array?

Given the simple schema below:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AddressSchema = new Schema({
  value: String
});

var AddressRangeSchema = new Schema({
  from: String,
  to: String
});

var AddressListSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  list: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
});
```

The `AddressList.list` can be made up of any number of `Address`, `AddressRange` or `AddressList`. Such as the following:

```
var firstAddr = new Address({
  value: "172.0.0.1"
});

var firstAddrRange = new AddressRange({
  from: "172.0.0.10",
  to: "172.0.0.20"
})

var firstList = new AddressList({
  name: "MyFirstList",
  list: [
    firstAddr.id,
    firstAddrRange.id
  ]
});
```

How can I pull the objects in the `list` array, given that they are one of three possible types?

Answer (score 0):

With Mongodb, only one collection at a time can be queried. An ORM layer like Mongoose may abstract this for you, but ultimately you're doing a separate query for each collection.

If the order of the items in your list doesn't matter this whole operation becomes much simpler. If order is important, you'll have to do more work.

Option 1)
Query all of the IDs against each collection. You can pass up to 16MB! worth of ids to in an $in query, so this will work even with huge collections.

```
AddressSchema.find({_id:{$in:allIds} }, callback);
AddressRangeSchema.find({_id:{$in:allIds} }, callback);
```

This will give you all of the items, and then you can manually go through and merge them into the correct order. For small sets of items (under 100) this is probably not a terrible option. You're indexing on the _id field, so cache hits and misses are pretty cheap.

Option 2)
Store metadata along with the _id that indicates the collection:

```
var AddressListSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  list: [{type:String, _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId}]
});

var firstList = new AddressList({
  name: "MyFirstList",
  list: [
    {type:'a', _id: firstAddr.id},
    {type:'ar',_id: firstAddrRange.id}
  ]
});
```

You can then do a query of each collection correctly. This will reduce your cache misses, but increase the size of your stored data in the AddressList collection. This pattern is especially useful if you have a Name or other field you want to cache and display in a partial view.

Option 3) Change your schema to nest all of the data

Not sure on your use case, but nesting the schema instead of having three separate collections may be the best bet.